# horizontall scrollview in tabhost does not work or make my content disappear

Tags: android, android-tabhost, horizontalscrollview

Well this is my main.xml which contains the tabhost:

Problem is that horizontal scrollview doesnot work. If I change the relative layout to linearlayout tabs are scrollable but I cannot see the main content od my activity - I just see the tabs.

I have also tried removing entirely the linear layout that contain the tabwidget but nothing changed.

If you need any other xml let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/tab_space_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/tab_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TabWidget>
            </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs">

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

any help?

Comment: Seems like your xml has a few extra things, maybe give [this](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/) a try?

Comment: Thanks it works! make it an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach listed in [this sample](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/) would solve your problem.